# Reconciling Behavior of $e^t$ and $e^{it}$ as $t$ goes to infinity

Tags: complex-numbers

Gilbert Strang's book on differential equations asks the reader to compare how $e^t$ and $e^{it}$ behave in the complex plane as $t \rightarrow \infty$. $e^t$ blows up along the real axis. Strang then says that $e^{it}$ traces a circle in the complex plane since $e^{it} = \cos(t) + i \sin(t)$. This makes sense when I consider Euler's formula by itself, but now, comparing the two functions, I'm confused. Why doesn't $e^{it}$ blow up (i.e. grow larger and larger) along the imaginary axis?

Edit 1: To clarify, $t$ is real.

Edit 2: I thought that blowing up means the function approaches positive or negative infinity. But $|e^{it}|$ is always $\leq 1$.

Comment: Because $t$ is a real variable, not complex.

Comment: Who told you $e^{it}$ doesn't blow up along the imaginary axis?

Comment: @Arthur well, I thought that blowing up means the function approaches positive or negative infinity. But $|e^{it}|$ is always $\leq 1$.

Comment: That is true if $t$ is real. But if $t=-2i$, $e^{it}=e^2>1$.

Comment: $t$ is real here. I'll add that to the original post.

Comment: Why should they behave similarly? A priori, given a function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ we shouldn't expect much symmetry between $$f_1:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}: r\mapsto f(r)$$ and $$f_2:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}:r\mapsto f(ir).$$ The two "slices" $f_1$ and $f_2$ of $f$ are looking at almost completely different "parts" of $f$ (the only relationship between them we're guaranteed is that $f_1(0)=f_2(0)$).

Comment: I don't know about what to expect a priori, but I thought that $i$ merely defined the direction in the complex plane.

Comment: I just realized my mistake. I was comparing $e^t$ with $ie^t$. But this is not equivalent to Strang's comparison of $e^t$ and $e^{it}$.